# Grid Layout Isn't Showing in Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to create some 4 grid layout which is have Constraint Layout as a root layout. The file is created to be as a fragment, but I think that won't be a problem, mentioned in title to describe it as detail as possible.

The xml file is looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
    tools:context=".view.LoanDetail">

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider_loan"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/line_white"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider_loan">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_money_outl"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin16"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Total Pinjaman"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_currency_dep"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin8"
            android:gravity="center|clip_vertical"
            android:text="IDR"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TEXTVIEW"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin8"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="100,000,000"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


    <GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin16"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin8"
    android:rowCount="2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout3">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin8"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin8"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin8"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin8"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/margin8">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin8"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin16"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin8"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin8">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pokok"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin24"
                android:text="IDR"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_loan_det_prim"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin8"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin8"
                android:text="100,000,000"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin8"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin8"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin8"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin8"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/margin8">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin8"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin16"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin8"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin8">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView14"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Angsuran"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView15"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin8"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin8"
                    android:text="TERTUNGGAK"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin24"
                android:text="IDR"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin8"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin8"
                android:text="500,000"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin8"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin8"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin8"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_green_primary"
                android:text="BAYARAN"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin8"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin8"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin8"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin8"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/margin8">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin8"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin16"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin8"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin8">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView18"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sisa Plafon"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView19"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin24"
                android:text="IDR"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView20"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin8"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin8"
                android:text="9,500,000"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin8"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin8"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin8"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin8"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/margin8">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin8"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin16"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin8"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin8">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView21"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tenor/Bunga Bulanan"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView22"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin8"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin24"
                android:text="12 / 0.50%"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</GridLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_green_dark"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin16"
    android:weightSum="4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_list_inactive"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Senarai Simpanan"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_inactive" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_apps"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Detil"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_history_inactive"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Transaksi"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_inactive" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_pen_inactive"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Aplikasi Baru"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_inactive" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And it should be looked like this (*screenshot taken from Android Studio preview*)

[image: grid layout preview]

But the output in the real device the Grid layout is not showing.
Is there a thing I miss?

*#Note: The rest layout is showed just fine no problem, only the GridLayout.*

Comment: can you please share what the design looks like as per the code

Comment: Can you please share complete xml, you have made references of layout "linearLayout3" and "linearLayout4" which are not found.

Comment: @nikk already update it sir

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal i did not found any issue. i checked in real device.. grid layout showing to me.

Answer (score 0):

Please set the height and width of the GridLayout, where you didn't define, please copy and paste the code as it is which is given below it will definitely work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:rowCount="2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
           >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
             >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Pokok"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="IDR"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_loan_det_prim"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="100,000,000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
          >
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/rel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
              >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView14"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Angsuran"
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView15"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="TERTUNGGAK"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:textSize="10sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView16"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="IDR"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView17"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="500,000"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:text="BAYARAN"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"

          >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
               >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView18"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Sisa Plafon"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView19"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="IDR"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView20"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="9,500,000"

                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
         >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView21"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Tenor/Bunga Bulanan"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView22"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="12 / 0.50%"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </GridLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `match_parent` isn't helping sir.. Speaking of which, the root layout I used is Constraint layout, and I used `match_constraint` to make it to depend on what constraint it so it become 0dp automatically..

If I change it to match_parent, then the constraint of my layout is overflowed

Comment: Hmm what's wrong then.. Have you check again I've update the post?

Comment: please set height and width of gridLayout only.

Comment: Hm, I can't explain it through words, so this is if using 0dp https://pasteboard.co/IxEpXRV.png and this is using your answer sir https://pasteboard.co/IxEqqG6.png

Answer (score 0):

```
  implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

[image: see the below image its shwowing]

```
  implementation'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Comment: That run on real device? How could that be, mine isn't working. I already implement both dependencies anyway..

Comment: yes it's working on real device, can you tell me on which device you are runing and and your Api level

Comment: I use Samsung J, running on API level 21 Lolipop.. Is it matter, related to GridLayout?